# Sign as a qualifier: Difference between +Number and Number+

Tags: notation

People often use the + sign to qualify numbers.

It's common to see this in resumes, e.g.:

> - Managed a +$1M portfolio
> - Lead interviews with 50+ people

- What is the exact meaning of the + sign in each of these cases?
- Does it mean exactly the same to have the + sign preceding *or* following a given number?

Comment: Oftentimes "$N+$" in context like this refers to a variable number of $N$ or more but still on the order of $N$ (*say, $50+$ could refer to some unknown number between 50 and 90, but it varies depending on context*), it wouldn't make sense to say "lead interviews with $50+$ people" if you in fact have led interviews with two million people.  In this context the significance of the + before or after doesn't seem to make any difference and I expect the meaning is the same.

Comment: It's not math and not legit.  So if they answer is it means as much or more, that is the answer.  There is nothing more to be said or discussed.